# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, date, datetime, pycharm

```
import datetime

current_datetime_demo = datetime.datetime.today()
print(current_datetime_demo)
```

I am using pycharm to run this and it keeps throwing this error when i try to print date and time

Comment: I'd guess you have a file named `datetime.py` - the standard library's `datetime` module _does_ have an attribute named `datetime`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you already imported `datetime` library you should do

```
current_datetime_demo = datetime.today()
```